# How to write a multiline Ansible Jinja2 variable?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a Ansible line that fails linting:

```
 tags: "{{ deployment_id | resource_tags('asg', base_resource_tags, deployment=deployment_id, deployment_env=deployment_env, deployment_name=deployment_name, purpose=deployment_purpose_tag, cpu_utilization=deployment_cpu_utilization_tag, disk_io_class=deployment_disk_io_tag, prom_exporters=deployment_prom_exporter_tags) | asg_tag_list }}"
```

How do I make this pass linting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a YAML Folding Scalar, `>` *without* quotes. Then append the "Strip" Block Chomping `-` ([docs](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534)) indicator to remove the trailing newline, in total it looks like `>-`. The below example will work correctly, with each newline translating to a space. Adding quotes will break it e.g.

```
tags: >-
    {{ deployment_id | resource_tags('asg', base_resource_tags, deployment=deployment_id,
    deployment_env=deployment_env, deployment_name=deployment_name, Purpose=deployment_purpose_tag,
    cpu_utilization=deployment_cpu_utilization_tag, disk_io_class=deployment_disk_io_tag,
    prom_exporters=deployment_prom_exporter_tags) | asg_tag_list }}
```

Comment: Including `-` after the fold operator (as in: `: >-`) will trim the trailing newline; your version is equivalent to `tags: "{{ ... }}\n"` which isn't what was in the original line

Comment: Related: How do I [break a string in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790454/9624052) over multiple lines?

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel, looks like I updated the answer a few years ago per your comment. Appreciate your input!